# Examples of SOA "enabled" software products?

Tags: soa

Can somebody provide real world examples of software products or applications (commercial or open source) that have SOA in them?

Like for example some X company claiming that the latest released version of their software product is now SOA compatible.

Answer (score 4):

SOA is not a specification that a software product could be claimed to be SOA compatible. Read more on what SOA is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

SOA is basically an architecture/implementation technique which aims towards *loose-coupling* of the presentation layer with the data layer. Thus, multiple services/modules/applications could access the same data and use it as per their need. This *loose-coupling* can lead to more of distributed programming. The day you see that a particular service is more in demand, you could add nodes to your cluster for the particular service.

Examples per se would be applications that were build with SOA architecture. Liferay (an open source Java CMS) is a service-based application. All application that expose some sort of an API (see programmableweb.com) can be termed as SOA-enabled where in you pull data and consume it the way you want.

**But yes, for sure, SOA is not a specification.**

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538710/reports-in-soa-business-intelligence-service-oriented-architecture ?